# how to show only part of other website in my site using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, maps

I am using maps from maps.nyc.gov. What i want to do is to show only map from this website in my own website.

Let say here is the sample URL:

http://maps.nyc.gov/doitt/nycitymap/?searchType=AddressSearch&addressNumber=498%20&street=7%20Avenue&borough=Manhattan

I only want to show map from this site in my website don't know how to do it.

I used iframe but it loads complete website.

We can also use maps from this site: Sample link:

http://www.oasisnyc.net/map.aspx?zoomto=lot:4004310027

Please Guide.
Thanks

Comment: First of all, you probably need to check if the website even allows this. If not, you have a potential lawsuit.

Comment: I am sure there is no legal issue in using map from http://www.oasisnyc.net/. This is a project for public use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did this using CSS.

Made an iframe and loaded that site in iframe and wrapped the iframe with a div.

Set the size of the div to the size of part of website you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

make an ajax call (of other technique), and only take part of the content you have retrieved on your site.

if only the map, then i think you need div tag mainCenter

Or ask if the have an API (like google maps)

Comment: but how can i only show div tag "mainCenter" and hide all other tags?